# finding a cell with variable data inside

Tags: vba, vlookup

This might be too easy for you but I can not find a solution.

I have a value in column O2 which has a variable number inside. I am trying to use the vlookup to see in which column i have the duplicate of the value inside of O2.

If the the value in O2 would be the same, then it would be easy to use vlookup. But the value inside of O2 varies as following.

O2= Company (variable value)is not defined

So how can i put this in a formula to be able to find matching cell with O2?

Comment: WorksheetFunction.VLookup(range("O2").value,range("A1:B10"),1)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use value from a range in a VBA VLookup formula, try something like this:

```
With Activesheet
    .Range("C1") = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("O2").value,.Range("A1:B10"),‌​1)
End with
```

The With Activesheet, couldbe changed to the sheet you need to use. If you are using only one sheet, try this:

`Range("C1") = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(range("O2").value,range("A1:B10"),‌​1)`